# Can't use await on ShowMessageAsync

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

I'm using Mahapp and I'm trying to wait for the result of the dialog, but the compiler underlined `ShowMessageAsync` and display me:

> ShowMessageAsync doesn't exist in the current context

this is the code:

```
private async void ShowMessageBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await ShowMessageAsync("Hello!", "Welcome to the world of metro!", 
        MahApps.Metro.Controls.MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
    if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
    {
        this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: OK");
    }
    else
    {
        this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: CANCEL");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added all the namespaces needed?

Comment: @WPMed Yes, I've added: `using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension method for mahapps async message box.

```
using System.Windows;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public static class InfoBox
{
    public async static Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowMessageAsync(string title, string Message, MessageDialogStyle style = MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, MetroDialogSettings settings = null)
    {
         return await ((MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow)).ShowMessageAsync(title, Message, style, settings);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var res = await InfoBox.ShowMessageAsync(...); 
if (res == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative) 
{ 
     /* Do something*/ 
}
```

Comment: This seems working but if I want get the result adding `.Result` to the end?

Comment: @Dillinger var res = await InfoBox.ShowMessageAsync(...) then if (res == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
                { /* Do something*/ }

Answer (score 1):

Example by adding a button with some actions:

XAML

```
 <Button 
            x:Name="btnAddCustomer"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10" Width="75"
            Click="ButtonAddCustomer_Click">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/add.jpg" Height="18"
                       Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Add"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
        
    </Button>
```

Code Behind:

```
private async void ButtonAddCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result =await this.ShowMessageAsync("Title", "Felipe", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
        if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
        {
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: OK");
            //^^^^ here
        }
        else
        {
            await this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: CANCEL");
            //^^^^ here
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add the `this` keyword because the `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method and not a member of the `MetroWindow` class.

```
var result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Hello!", ...);
                 //^^^^^ here
```

You have another error. Instead of:

```
 MahApps.Metro.Controls.MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative
```

Use:

```
MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative
```

And you must add await before these lines:

```
if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
{
    await this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: OK");
   //^^^^ here
}
else
{
    await this.ShowMessageAsync("Result", "You said: CANCEL");
   //^^^^ here
}
```

Comment: If I add `this.` there is another error: `'MessageDialogResult' does not contain a definition of 'GetAwaiter' and has not been found no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'MessageDialogResult'. Probably missing a using directive or an assembly reference.`

Comment: I have the same error message but with the ShowMetroDialogAsync method.