# Implement Mahapps MessageBox with OK and Cancel

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, mahapps.metro

I am trying to implement `Mahapps Metro Message box` in my code, but want to use it on a `class`, not any `WPF Window` , can I achieve this ?, because I don't want to use ordinary `Message Boxes`.

```
switch(x)
{
   case "a":
   //Do something
   break;
   case "b":
   var result = MessageBox.Show("TitleMessage","If you want to continue",MessageboxButton.YesNo); 
  break;
}
```

so instead of this `MessageBox`, I want to use `Mahapps Message Box` , then use this result variable.

Comment: The Mahapps Message Box runs inside the active window, so you will need a window.

Answer (score 3):

Since the ShowMessageAsync method is an extension method of the MetroWindow class, you need to have a window to be able to call it.

If your applications's main window is a metro window you should be able to call the method like this from any class that has a reference to the PresentationFramework assembly:

```
var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow); 
await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("title", "message...");
```

Please refer to the following links for more information: 
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1129

[Can't use await on ShowMessageAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319540/cant-use-await-on-showmessageasync)